# Reset input fields in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have a Dialog to input details. At the first time , ***InputText*** are empty.
But from the second input, ***InputText*** maintain the previous value.

This is my code :

```xml
     <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton1" type="button" value="add" onclick="dlg1.show()" update="firstname1"/>
     <p:dialog id="dialogAjout" header="add department" widgetVar="dlg1" resizable="false">  
          <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
                <h:outputLabel for="firstname1" value="Libellé :" />  
                <p:inputText id="firstname1" value="#{departementBean.departement.libelleDepartement}" />
          </h:panelGrid>  
          <p:commandButton id="submitButton1" value="Valider" oncomplete="dlg1.hide();" action="#{departementBean.addDept()}" update="tabView"/> 
     </p:dialog>
```

How can I resolve this, please !!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this primefaces component:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml
Regarding dialogs in general: don't put them inside forms.
Have this instead: `<p:dialog><h:form>...`
Regarding update="" values, if your appendToBody is true, put a colon in front of the id (that means it`s in another form).

Answer (score 6):

You should use the following code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Reset" style="margin-right:20px;">
    <p:ajax update="registrationForm" resetValues="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: You just specify id of respective control in update="" attribute.Here I have done it for entire form by writing id i.e(registrationForm) as update="registrationForm"

Comment: @Dragos answer covers this with link to PF showcase. Plus you may want to use `p:commandButton` as the questioner is already using it.

Answer (score 5):

Add `resetValues="true"` to your commandButton

```xml
<p:commandButton resetValues="true" action="#{departementBean.prepareDialog}"  id="showDialogButton1" type="button" value="add" oncomplete="dlg1.show()" update=":dialogAjout"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

modify you open button like this : open dialog in `oncomplete` and before that update it by adding its id to `update` attribute and add action method to do the server side logic to actually init the dialog fields (populate / reset)

```
<p:commandButton action="#{departementBean.prepareDialog}"  id="showDialogButton1" type="button" value="add" oncomplete="dlg1.show()" update=":dialogAjout"/>
```

b.t.w it looks like your dialog located inside your form together with your opening button , this is a "bad practice" move your dialog away from that form and place a   new form inside the dialog , e.g `<p:dialog><h:form>` ...

Comment: Thank you Daniel , but an other problem is appeared. When I put <p:dialog><h:form> ... out side of the principal form , the dialog can not be appeared. Why ?!!

Comment: try to change update attribute by leaving it like this update=":dialogAjout" also, have you implemented the prepareDialog method or at least removed it from commandButton ? what error message do you see? server / javascript ?

Comment: Thanks Daniel : I added this in my **Bean** :

`private Departement departement = new Departement();
\\getter and setter
public void preparDialog(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        departement = new Departement();
    }
`

Insert work fine in the database , The dialog appear but it keeps the previous value. Any idea please

Comment: were your preparDialog method even called? cause the signature is of actionListener and not action... yous should decalre it like this preparDialog() { departement = new Departement(); }

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question thus

```
<p:dialog header="myDialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
   <h:outputLabel for="fild1" value="Fill the field" /> 
   <p:password id="fild1" value="#{myBean.attribute}" required="false" label="Field" redisplay="false" /><br />
   <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.method()}" value="Send" oncomplete="dlg1.hide()" update="field1" />
</p:dialog>
```

When I used the attribute **update="field1"** of p:commandButton.
The value of field **p:password will empty** after submitting the form.

I tried do the suggestion of Dani but my attribute going empty when I submitted my  form and not stayed empty after submit